# How to use a .js file to display a webpage using document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I'm sure this is obvious but its driving me crazy. I have an assignment where we create an order form page. The last part of it involves making a conformation page display after the user enters their information. We are supposed to use document.write() to create the webpage in a function called displayOutput(), which is called by a previous function. My problem is that I have no idea how to build a webpage using document.write(). Nothing i've put in the displayOutput() function writes to the page. All that happens is the original order form page pops up. What am I not doing?

1. Here's a tiny chunk of my displayOutput() function.

   ```
            document.write("<body>");

                      document.write("<div id='container'>");

                       document.write("<div id='header'>");

                          displayHeader();


                       document.write("</div>");

                     document.write("</div>");

              document.write("</body>");
   ```
2. Also, please remember I HAVE to use document.write()

Answer (score 0):

Open a new window and apply document.write method with that reference. Use `window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)` method.
For example: myWindow is a reference of new window here.

```
<script>
var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
myWindow.document.write("<body><div id='container'><div id='header'>"+displayHeader()+"</div></div></body>");
</script>
```

If you want to open this window on new page, replace `_self` with `_blank` etc.

Hope, it will work for you.

Comment: It has to be a page created completely with document.write(). I can't create a page, then just write it. Each part has to be written like that

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Historiun: What do you mean by `page created`? Do you want to open a new window?